# Variable not defined in a nested window with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, spyder

I´m making a GUI with Python and Tkinter (python version 3.11.3 and Spyder).

The GUI is for control of some kind of machine (like a logfile but simpler).
In root window (ventana principal) when I click "No aceptable" (boton_flujo_2) another window is opened with Toplevel (called "Ventana 1"). In that window I want that if "No necesario 2" is checked, the buttons in that window should be disabled.
I use the same logic in "Ventana principal" and it worked but when i want to use in "Ventana 1" I have the next error:

`"NameError: name 'mensual_check_top1' is not defined"`

My code is the next one:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 

#Para deshabilitar widgets segun ciertas condiciones    
def disable_widgets():
    # disable dropdown menu si Valve Status "0 (cero)" esta checkeado
    if cero_check.get() == 1:
        dropdown.config(state='disabled')
    else:
        dropdown.config(state='readonly')

  # disable flujo box si "5lpm" esta checkeado
    if flow_check.instate(['selected']):
        flow_entry.config(state='disabled')
    else:
        flow_entry.config(state='normal')
        
  # disable boton_flujo widget en CONTROL MENSUAL si "no necesario" esta checkeado
    if control_mensual_check.instate(['selected']):
        boton_flujo_1.config(state='disabled')
        boton_flujo_2.config(state='disabled')
        #boton_flujo_3.config(state='disabled')
        #boton_flujo_4.config(stapte='disabled')
    else:
        boton_flujo_1.config(state='normal')
        boton_flujo_2.config(state='normal')
       # boton_flujo_3.config(state='normal')
       # boton_flujo_4.config(state='normal')
         
  # disable boton_flujo widget en Ventana 1 si "No necesario 2" esta checked
    if mensual_check_top1.instate(['selected']):
        boton_flujo_3.config(state='disabled')
        boton_flujo_4.config(state='disabled')
    else:
        boton_flujo_3.config(state='normal')
        boton_flujo_4.config(state='normal')
        
#Para que Status solo admita numeros
def validate_numeric_input(new_value):
    return new_value.isnumeric()

#Ventana 1
def realizar_calibracion():
    
 
    ventana1 = tk.Toplevel(root)
    ventana1.geometry("300x100")
    ventana1.title("Ventana 1")

    verif_flujo_mensual = ttk.Label(ventana1, text="Verificacion de flujo")
    verif_flujo_mensual.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
    mensual_check_top1 = ttk.Checkbutton(ventana1, text="No necesario 2", command=disable_widgets)
    mensual_check_top1.grid(row=2, column=0)

    boton_flujo_3 = ttk.Button(ventana1, text="Aceptable")
    boton_flujo_3.grid(row=2, column=1)

    boton_flujo_4 = ttk.Button(ventana1, text="No aceptable")#,command=realizar_calibracion)
    boton_flujo_4.grid(row=2, column=2)
    

#Ventana Principal (root)
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Ventana Principal") 
root.geometry("800x600")

# OPERADOR
operador_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Operador")
operador_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
operador_entry = ttk.Entry(root)
operador_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

# STATUS. VALIDO INGRESO SOLO DE NUMEROS
status_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Status")
status_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
status_entry = ttk.Entry(root, validate="key")
status_entry['validatecommand'] = (status_entry.register(validate_numeric_input), '%P')
status_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

# VALVE STATUS
valve_status_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Valve Status")
valve_status_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

    # si 0 cero check, desplegable deshabilitado 
cero_check = tk.IntVar()
cero_checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="0 (cero)", variable=cero_check, command=disable_widgets)
cero_checkbox.grid(row=2, column=1)

    # desplegable para opciones de Valve Status que no son cero
options_var = tk.StringVar()
options = [" Otro valor ","01011 : Derivación", "01100 : Calentamiento/Aire limpio", "00000 : Medida", "00010 : Calibración medidor de flujo"]
dropdown = ttk.OptionMenu(root, options_var, *options)
dropdown.grid(row=2, column=2)

# APARIENCIA DEL FILTRO CON DESPLEGABLE
apariencia_filtro_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Apariencia Filtro")
apariencia_filtro_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

apariencia_filtro_options = ["APARIENCIA","Normal", "Achucharrado", "Marron"]
apariencia_filtro_var = tk.StringVar(value="")
apariencia_filtro_dropdown = ttk.OptionMenu(root, apariencia_filtro_var, *apariencia_filtro_options)
apariencia_filtro_dropdown.grid(row=3, column=1)

# FLUJO. 
flow_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Flujo")
flow_label.grid(row=4, column=0)
    # si 5lpm checkeado, deshabilito blank box
flow_check = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="5lpm", command=disable_widgets)
flow_check.grid(row=4, column=1)
    #blank box
flow_entry = ttk.Entry(root)
flow_entry.grid(row=4, column=2)

# CINTA REEMPLAZADA
replacement_tape_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Cinta reemplazada?")
replacement_tape_label.grid(row=5, column=0)

    #checkbutton para cinta reemplazada
replacement_tape_check = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Si")
replacement_tape_check.grid(row=5, column=1)


# DIVISION
division_label = ttk.Label(root, text="------------------------------")
division_label.grid(row=7, column=1)


# TITULO CHECKLIST GENERAL
general_label = ttk.Label(root, text="CHECKLIST GENERAL")
general_label.grid(row=8, column=1)


# CHECKLIST GENERAL
big_checkbox_var = tk.IntVar()
big_checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(root, width=0)
big_checkbox.grid(row=9, column=1, rowspan=4)

    # Hora actual + hora instrumento
hora_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Chequeo hora actual + instrumento")
hora_label.grid(row=9, column=0)


    # Inspeccion caño y manguera
mangueras_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Inspeccion caños y mangueras")
mangueras_label.grid(row=10, column=0)


    # Trampa agua interna
aguainterna_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Inspeccion trampa de agua interna")
aguainterna_label.grid(row=11, column=0)

    # Trampa agua externa
aguaexterna_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Inspeccion trampa de agua externa")
aguaexterna_label.grid(row=12, column=0)

# DIVISION
division_label = ttk.Label(root, text="------------------------------")
division_label.grid(row=13, column=1)

# CONTROL MENSUAL
general_label = ttk.Label(root, text="CONTROL MENSUAL")
general_label.grid(row=14, column=1) 

# create label for mangueras
verif_flujo = ttk.Label(root, text="Verificacion de flujo")
verif_flujo.grid(row=15, column=0)

control_mensual_check = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="No necesario", command=disable_widgets)
control_mensual_check.grid(row=15, column=1)

boton_flujo_1 = ttk.Button(root, text="Aceptable")
boton_flujo_1.grid(row=15, column=2)

boton_flujo_2 = ttk.Button(root, text="No aceptable",command=realizar_calibracion)
boton_flujo_2.grid(row=15, column=3)


root.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance!

FQ

I use the same logic in "Ventana principal" and it worked but when i want to use in "Ventana 1" I have the next error:

`"NameError: name 'mensual_check_top1' is not defined"`.

I also tried making global variables but it neither worked.

Comment: You having too many errors

Comment: `mensual_check_top1` is a local variable inside the `realizar_calibracion()` function.  It is not available inside of the `disable_widgets()` function where you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your issue using the code you provided. I believe I was also able to fix the problems you were mentioning to have your desired result.

The main problem with your code for "Ventana 1" is that all the variables are classified within a function which is not the case for "Ventana principal." This is why it is giving you "not defined" errors. To fix this you simply need to make the variables global so they can be used from within the `disable_widgets` function. Below are the changes I made to get it to work.

```
#Ventana 1
def realizar_calibracion():

    ventana1 = tk.Toplevel(root)
    ventana1.geometry("300x100")
    ventana1.title("Ventana 1")

    verif_flujo_mensual = ttk.Label(ventana1, text="Verificacion de flujo")
    verif_flujo_mensual.grid(row=0, column=1)
 
    global mensual_check_top1 
    mensual_check_top1 = ttk.Checkbutton(ventana1, text="No necesario 2", command=disable_widgets)
    mensual_check_top1.grid(row=2, column=0)

    global boton_flujo_3
    boton_flujo_3 = ttk.Button(ventana1, text="Aceptable")
    boton_flujo_3.grid(row=2, column=1)

    global boton_flujo_4
    boton_flujo_4 = ttk.Button(ventana1, text="No aceptable")#,command=realizar_calibracion)
    boton_flujo_4.grid(row=2, column=2)
```

As you can see, I just made `mensual_check_top1`, `boton_flujo_3`, and `boton_flujo_4` all global variables so they can be used from outside of the `realizar_calibracion` function.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `mensual_check_top1` is a local variable defined inside `realizar_calibracion()`, so it cannot be accessed outside the function.

I would suggest to make `disable_widgets()` a generic function as below:

```py
def disable_widgets(checkvar, widgets):
    state = tk.DISABLED if checkvar.instate(['selected']) else tk.NORMAL
    for w in widgets:
        w.config(state=state)
```

Then update those `command=disable_widgets` as below:

```py
...
def realizar_calibracion():
    ...
    mensual_check_top1 = ttk.Checkbutton(ventana1, text="No necesario 2",
                                         command=lambda: disable_widgets(mensual_check_top1, [boton_flujo_3, boton_flujo_4]))
    ...

...
cero_checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="0 (cero)", variable=cero_check,
                                command=lambda: disable_widgets(cero_checkbox, [dropdown]))
...
flow_check = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="5lpm",
                             command=lambda: disable_widgets(flow_check, [flow_entry]))
...
control_mensual_check = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="No necesario",
                                        command=lambda: disable_widgets(control_mensual_check, [boton_flujo_1, boton_flujo_2]))
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this error can be prevented if `mensual_check_top1` is created outside of the `realizar_calibracion()` function.

Try moving the line where you create that Checkbutton (the one shown below) outside of the function. You can leave the `.grid()` command inside the function so that the button doesn't appear until the function is executed.

```py
mensual_check_top1 = ttk.Checkbutton(ventana1, text="No necesario 2", command=disable_widgets)
```

**Edit:** move the definition of `ventana1` and other necessary widgets outside of the function also. Thus, your widgets and windows are defined outside of functions and configured/packed inside of functions. This avoids using `global`.

Comment: Then `ventana1` will be undefined.

Comment: Good catch, move `ventana1 = tk.Toplevel(root)` out of the function too. That avoids using the `global` keyword.

Comment: It is a bad suggestion as I think OP wants the window to be open when the button is clicked, not at program starts.

Comment: If you define 'ventana1' and 'mensual_check_top1' outside of the function, that would fix the problem with 'mensual_check_top1" as being undefined. But the reason this was all happening is because of the 'disable_widgets" function which also needs reference to the buttons 'boton_flujo_3' and 'boton_flujo_4'. using your method, you would also have to reference those outside the function as well. While possible, at this point you would have declared all the variables for the realizar_calibracion function outside of the function. In my opinion, this scatters them and doesn't keep it all together.

Comment: This is why i submitted my answer the way I did. It fixes the overall problem of having 'mensual_check_top1', 'boton_flujo_3', and 'boton_flujo_4'. all undefined when accessed from the 'disable_widgets' function but still leaves everything compartmentalized within the 'realizar_calibracion' function, like it was originally.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @alantbarlow. It does depend on when OP wants each piece to run. I've had more issues (i.e. made more mistakes) when placing widgets into `global` namespace with the keyword than when separating creation and configuration for widgets/windows.